# Browser tab freezes after using useState hook in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a blog app and it worked perfectly before I have added the user login feature. After that useState hook methods freeze the application tab in the browser. I am not sure what the problem is, I am guessing it has something to do with re-rendering.

Here is my App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Header from './components/Header'
import Filter from './components/Filter'
import AddNewBlog from './components/AddNewBlog'
import Blogs from './components/Blogs'
import blogService from './services/blogs'
import Notification from './components/Notification'
import Button from './components/Button'
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm'
import loginService from './services/login'
import './App.css'



const App = () => {
  const [ blogs, setBlogs] = useState([]) 
  const [ newTitle, setNewTitle ] = useState('')
  const [ newAuthor, setNewAuthor ] = useState('')
  const [ newUrl, setNewUrl ] = useState('')
  const [ newLike, setNewLike ] = useState('')
  const [ blogsToShow, setBlogsToShow] = useState(blogs)
  const [ message, setMessage] = useState(null)
  const [ notClass, setNotClass] = useState(null)
  const [ username, setUsername ] = useState('')
  const [ password, setPassword ] = useState('')
  const [ user, setUser ] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    blogService
      .getAll()
      .then(initialBlogs => {
        setBlogs(initialBlogs)
        console.log(initialBlogs)
        setBlogsToShow(initialBlogs)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        showMessage(`Error caught: ${error}`, 'error')
      })

  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    const loggedUserJSON = window.localStorage.getItem('loggedBlogappUser')
    if (loggedUserJSON) {
      const user = JSON.parse(loggedUserJSON)
      setUser(user)
      blogService.setToken(user.token)
    }
  })

  const handleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    try {
      const user = await loginService.login({
        username, password,
      })

      window.localStorage.setItem('loggedBlogappUser', JSON.stringify(user))

      blogService.setToken(user.token)
      setUser(user)
      setUsername('')
      setPassword('')
    } catch (error) {
      showMessage('wrong credentials', 'error')
    }
  }

  const handleLogout = () => {
    console.log('logging out')
    setUser(null)
    window.localStorage.clear()
  }


  const handleAddClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if(newTitle === '') {
      alert("Input Title")
    }
    else if (newAuthor === '') {
      alert("Input Author")
    }
    else if (newUrl === '') {
      alert("Input Url")
    } else {
      let newObject = {
        title: newTitle,
        author: newAuthor,
        url: newUrl,
        likes: 0
      }
      console.log('step0');

      blogService
        .create(newObject)
        .then(returnedBlog => {
          setBlogs(blogs.concat(returnedBlog))
          setBlogsToShow(blogs.concat(returnedBlog))
          resetForm()
          showMessage(`Added ${newTitle}`, 'success')
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error.response.data)
          showMessage(`${error.response.data.error}`, 'error')
        })
      //}
    }
  }

  const handleDeleteClick = (id, title) => {
    let message = `Do you really want to delete ${title}?`
    if(window.confirm(message)){
      blogService
        .deleteBlog(id)
        .then(res => {
          setBlogs(blogs.filter(b => b.id !== id))
          setBlogsToShow(blogs.filter(b => b.id !== id))
        })
        .catch(error => {
          showMessage(`${title} has already been removed from the server`, 'error')
        })
    }
  }

  const handleLikeClick = (blog) => {
    const updatedObject = {
      ...blog,
      likes: blog.likes += 1
    }

    blogService
      .update(updatedObject)
      .then(() => {
        setBlogs(blogs)
        showMessage(`You liked ${updatedObject.title}`, 'success')
      })
  }

  const resetForm = () => {
    setNewTitle('')
    setNewAuthor('')
    setNewUrl('')
    setNewLike('')
    document.getElementById('titleInput0').value = ''
    document.getElementById('authorInput0').value = ''
    document.getElementById('urlInput0').value = ''
  }

  const showMessage = (msg, msgClass) => {
    setMessage(msg)
    setNotClass(msgClass)
    setTimeout(() => {
      setMessage(null)
      setNotClass(null)
    }, 5000)
  }

  const handleFilterOnChange = (e) => {
    const filtered = blogs.filter(blog => blog.title.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase()))
    setBlogsToShow(filtered)
    //setBlogs(filtered)
  }

  const handleAddTitleOnChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
    console.log(newTitle)

    setNewTitle(e.target.value)
  }

  const handleAddAuthorOnChange = (e) => {
    setNewAuthor(e.target.value)
  }

  const handleAddUrlOnChange = (e) => {
    setNewUrl(e.target.value)
  }

  if (user === null) {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header text={'Bloglist'} />
        <Notification message={message} notClassName={notClass} />
        <LoginForm 
          handleLogin={handleLogin}
          username={username}
          setUsername={setUsername} 
          password={password}
          setPassword={setPassword}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Header text={'Bloglist'} />
      <Notification message={message} notClassName={notClass} />
      <p>{user.name} logged in</p><Button text={"logout"} handleClick={handleLogout} />
      <AddNewBlog 
        handleAddTitleOnChange={handleAddTitleOnChange} 
        handleAddAuthorOnChange={handleAddAuthorOnChange}
        handleAddUrlOnChange={handleAddUrlOnChange}
        handleAddClick={handleAddClick}
      />
      <Filter handleFilterOnChange={handleFilterOnChange} />

      <Blogs blogs={blogsToShow} handleDeleteClick={handleDeleteClick} handleLikeClick={handleLikeClick} />      
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Anytime I call anyone of these methods: "setNewTitle, setNewAuthor, setNewUrl, setBlogsToShow", after logging in, the tab of the browser freezes. I tried with Chrome and FireFox.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your useEffect

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const loggedUserJSON = window.localStorage.getItem('loggedBlogappUser')
    if (loggedUserJSON) {
      const user = JSON.parse(loggedUserJSON)
      setUser(user)
      blogService.setToken(user.token)
    }
  })
```

It is executed on each re-render since it has not been provided any dependency and so it send the app in an infinite loop as it itself triggers a re-render. So when you call any state updater, this useEffect is triggered causing you tab to freeze

You can make this useEffect run once on initial render by passing an empty array to it as dependency

```
useEffect(() => {
    const loggedUserJSON = window.localStorage.getItem('loggedBlogappUser')
    if (loggedUserJSON) {
      const user = JSON.parse(loggedUserJSON)
      setUser(user)
      blogService.setToken(user.token)
    }
  }, [])
```